# How to return mouse-click x,y values to variables in turtle?

Tags: python, click, mouseevent, python-turtle

How do I return the x, y values of a click to variables x, y? (With the turtle library)

I've seen this code:

```
import turtle

def get_mouse_click_coor(x, y):
    turtle.onscreenclick(None)
    print(x, y)

turtle.onscreenclick(get_mouse_click_coor)

turtle.mainloop()
```

Problem is that it only prints the values of x and y. Is there any way I can get the (x, y)-values of a click returned, and then assigned to variables?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) for the turtle library that you can look
there is onclick(), onrelease(). etc.

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()
def show_pos(x, y):
    print(x, y)
screen.listen()
screen.onclick(show_pos)
while True:
    screen.update()
```

but if you want to store them you can do:

```
import turtle
cordinates = []
screen = turtle.Screen()
def show_pos(x, y):
    xycor = (x, y)
    cordinates.append(xycor)
    print(x, y) #this line prints where you clicked you can remove this line
    print(cordinates) #shows the coordinates you clicked in tuple
screen.listen()
screen.onclick(show_pos)
while True:
    screen.update()
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30413250)

Comment: Thank you. I will try to add more